# Chrome separating Arabic letters fix does not appear to work in iOS Chrome

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, webkit, arabic

Let's say I have the Arabic word الكتاب where each letter is programatically split up and placed inside HTML span elements:

باتكلا

There used to be an issue in WebKit that would result in the letters being rendered separately as ا ل ك ت ا ب instead of joining together as a word. This was fixed at some point and the code works as expected on Windows and Android Chrome browsers.

But the iOS Chrome browser on the other hand continues to render the word as separate letters. I am at my wits end trying to make it work. This is the first of two major issues where Chrome is working differently on iOS than the other systems.

The issue appears in Safari as well and I'm hoping any fix will work for Safari as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using the Zero Space Width (\u200D) but this does not work. Not only does it still have white spaces (albeit less than before) between each letter, but because I am programmatically splitting the Arabic words and placing each character in a span, it incorrectly uses the wrong endings for letters.